# Inheritance not allowing me to create an object of subclass?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

```
   class Animal {

    String type;
    int size;

    public Animal(String name, int size)
    {
        this.type = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Animal ()
    {

    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I can run!");
    }

}


class Cat extends Animal {

    String color;

    public void meow() {
        System.out.println("I can meow!");
    }

}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        Animal cat = new Cat();

        cat.meow();
        cat.run();

     }
}
```

Why is it when I try to create a new Cat object from the superclass Animal, I get an error with the .meow() part of the code. Specifically "error: cannot find symbol cat.meow();" . Aren't I creating a Cat object so shouldn't it have access to the methods in there?

Comment: You aren't being prevented from creating an instance. You are being prevented from invoking a method on the subclass, via a reference to an instance of the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Animal` is the base class. If you extend `Animal` you can add additional methods and instance variables in that class, which you actually did correctly.

As soon as you instantiate a child class (class that extends the base class, e.g.: `new Cat()`) but assign it to the type of the base class (`Animal`) you can only call the methods that are available there, i.e. in your case you could only call methods that are declared in the `Animal` class.

Lets assume you have a class `Animal` :

```java
public class Animal {
  public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Default sound");
  }
}
```

Now you create a class `Cat` that extends `Animal`:

```java
public class Cat extends Animal {
  private int catProperty = 5;

  //Override method of base class
  public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Meow");
  }

  public int getCatProperty(){
    return this.catProperty;
  }
}
```

An another class called `Dog` that extends `Animal`:

```java
public class Dog extends Animal {
  private int dogProperty = 8;

  //Override method of base class
  public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Woof");
  }

  public int getDogProperty(){
    return this.dogProperty;
  }
}
```

Since `Animal` is the base class you can now create an `array of type Animal` which holds `Cats` and `Dogs`.

```java
Animal[] animals = new Animal[2];
animals[0] = new Cat();
animals[1] = new Dog();

for (Animal animal : animals) {
  animal.makeSound();
}
```

Each of the `animals` (`Cat` and `Dog`) will now print the proper sound.
In case you really need to call a **child class specific method**, you have to **cast the object back to an instance of that child class**. In that case you have to be sure of what type the child class is.

E.g.:

```java
for (Animal animal : animals) {
  // Calls overriden method
  animal.makeSound();
  // This is illegal. Method getCatProperty is not declared in Animal  
  animal.getCatProperty();
  // This is illegal. Method getDogProperty is not declared in Animal class
  animal.getDogProperty();

  /*
   * IF YOU HAVE TO CALL CHILD CLASS SPECIFIC METHODS, DO IT LIKE THIS:
   */

  // Checks if animal is of type Cat
  if (animal instanceof Cat) {
    // Casts animal to instance of Cat
    Cat cat = (Cat) animal;
    // Calls specific Cat instance method
    System.out.println(cat.getCatProperty());
  }

  // Checks if animal is of type Dog
  if (animal instanceof Dog) {
    // Casts animal to instance of Dog
    Dog dog = (Dog) animal;
    // Calls specific Dog instance method
    System.out.println(dog.getDogProperty());
  }
}
```

Just as a sidenote: If you plan not to directly create instances of Animal (`Animal a = new Animal()`), you should declare the class itself and the methods that should be overriden by child classes as `abstract`.

```java
public abstract class Animal {
  public abstract void makeSound();
}
```

Also, in case that base class only has methods and no instance variables that should be available to the child classes, it's probably better use an interface instead of a (`abstract`) class.

```java
public interface Animal {
  public abstract void makeSound();
}
```

The interface then has to be `implemented` (not `extended`) by the concrete class.

```java
public class Cat implements Animal {
  public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Meow");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: your source examples are riddled with typos and wrong syntax. Please do better. Over time, hundreds of people will read your content. Dont confuse them with "java like" code that wont even compile.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica, yes, you are completely right. Thanks for the hint. Everything should be correct now.  Next time i'll directly code in in my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

> Animal cat = new Cat()

The compiler "forgets" that you created a *Cat* instance.

Your sourcecode says: I have a variable named `cat` that is an instance of `Animal`.

There is no method `meow()` on the Animal class.

If you want to call a subclass method, you need a **subclass** instance:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.meow();
```

or you need to *cast*. Basically you tell the compiler: "I know better than you".

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
( (Cat) cat).meow();
```

The point is: java is statically typed. In python, the interpreter would just see if that `cat` thingy has a method called `meow()` that it could call. Doesn't work like that in Java.

Comment: So what would the purpose of creating an instance of Animal a = new Cat();  be? I've seen online that one of the things inheritance allows is given class A is a superclass and class B is a subclass, you can have A obj = new B(); but now I don't see the purpose of this if it's just creating an instance of A, which doesn't have access to methods in B.

Comment: @krauser126 You use the base class when you don't care about specific subclasses. Image you have a "Command" class for example, that has an "execute" method. And many many different subclasses. But all your other code only cares about the Command object. You have maybe lists of Commands, and the only thing you do: invoke that execute method. But please note: these are really very basic OOP questions. That stuff is written up in any good book. Always try to do good research first. Asking others should be your *last* option, not your first approach ...